# SQL Server 2005 query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

My application need to get data from a SQL Server database. My problem is that there is 3 tables that has to be joined into a view. This takes a lot of time (about 30 sec to generate the view) So I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this SQL query?

SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Request1.RequestID,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Sending.Barcode,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.AdrID,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Name,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Street,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.HouseNo,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Postal,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.City,
                         TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Country,
                         Request1.Latitude,
                         Request1.Longitude,
                         Request1.ReceivedDate
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT RequestID,
                        Ltrim([Content]) AS Barcode,
                        Latitude,
                        Longitude,
                        ReceivedDate
        FROM   RequestWithLocation
        WHERE  ( Site LIKE '%Z' )
               AND ( [Content] <> '' )
               AND ( AddressID = '0' )
               AND ReceivedDate > Dateadd(day, -7, Getdate())) AS Request1
       INNER JOIN TrackIT.dbo.Sending
         ON Request1.Barcode = TrackIT.dbo.Sending.Barcode
       INNER JOIN TrackIT.dbo.Address_View
         ON TrackIT.dbo.Sending.DeliveryAdrID = TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.AdrID
ORDER  BY AdrID
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Well - this condition: `(Site LIKE '%Z')` is definitely going to **kill** all your performance - since it's a `LIKE` with a leading `%` - no indexes will ever be able to be used.....

Comment: Is there any way to get all data from the Site column without using LIKE "%Z" ?

Comment: Can you just drop that one condition, and see if performance improves?

Comment: after running it 6 times, 3 with LIKE in the query and 3 Without. The 3 times with the LIKE took 17 sec, and without it it took 20 to 22 sec. When i use the Estimate Execution Plan function in MS SQL i get the same result for both queries

Comment: The Execution plan is huge and i would'nt be able to combine it in one image. The tables are not indexed.

Comment: So you are asking us how to optimise a query involving a view without giving us either the definition of the view or the execution plan?

Comment: The view is generated by this sql statement. And i would be happy to give you an execution plan for the query, but how ??

Comment: [Execution Plan](http://prntscr.com/izv3q) i hope this is enough..

Answer (score 0):

You should add indexes on the join fields to your tables.

Answer (score -1):

Hi can you please try indexed view

For reference : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc917715.aspx